# R - Convert CHR to Date

Tags: r

I'm looking for a way to convert a `chr` to date. The current format of the csv is like this: `"Jul 6, 2004"`

when I try

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date)
```

I get this error:

> Error in charToDate(x) : 
>     character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the `format` of your date string, e.g. in your case

```
ss <- "Jul 6, 2004"   
as.Date(ss, format = "%b %d, %Y")
#[1] "2004-07-06"
```

See `?Date` for details, and `?strptime` for a description of all conversion specifications.

If `format` is not explicitly given, `as.Date` (by default) assumes the string to be in either `"%Y-%m-%d"` or `"%Y/%m/%d"` format.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `lubridate`:

```
test<-"Jul 6, 2004"
lubridate::mdy(test)
#[1] "2004-07-06"
```

Comment: I want to follow up on this as still not solved. The column has two distinct formats. One is "Jun 30, 2019" or just the Year such as 2021. I guess I need a more advanced function or something to correct the column given that either format could be encountered.

Comment: You can and should ask a nnew question. It's difficult to know what the goal is,sorry.

Comment: Figured it out with some outside help. Since the column has two distinct formats, we realized the easiest way to clean it up was to take the last 4 characters in the column. That was the key because it was the common link between the two formats.